# Laravel - Checking for a new messages with websocket

Tags: laravel, websocket, socket.io

I built my first app in Laravel and I am wondering what is the best way to check for a new messages while you are in conversation with someone? This is how conversation looks now: http://prntscr.com/t976tx .

I want to check for a new message without reloading a page and constantly listening that event.

I was reading about Socket.io and I have no idea how to start with that..i am using Laravel 5.7

Comment: Take a look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/broadcasting

Comment: I recommend Pusher since it's way easier to use and works completely fine

Comment: Is pusher free for this service? @Kabelbaan

Comment: @thefallen thanks for this, will try to figure it

Comment: I think the sandbox Pusher account has 100 max connections, but you can use this instead https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets